# Different sizes of file in storing String v/s ByteArray in File android

Tags: java, android, string, file, arrays

I am using this approach for storing data in a file from responce of Server.

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 response.getEntity().writeTo(outstream);
 byte[] responseBody = outstream.toByteArray();
 String data = new String(responseBody);
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(my_path));

 out.write(data.getBytes());

 out.flush();

 out.close();
```

It's working fine and my file gets created and size of it is 3786 bytes.

Now consider this ,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 response.getEntity().writeTo(outstream);
 byte[] responseBody = outstream.toByteArray();

 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(my_path));

 out.write(responseBody);

 out.flush();

 out.close();
```

it gives filesize of 1993 bytes.

Can anybody help me understand this , Does this  `new String(responseBody)` do something to responcebytes like some encoding ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, constructing a `String` from bytes decodes the bytes according to the current default character encoding (if one is not explicitly specified). Also `String.getBytes()` does the same in reverse (and may not necessarily produce the same sequence of bytes that was used to create it). A `String` holds text. If your data is raw binary data and is intended to be treated as such, you should not be storing it in a `String`, you should be storing it in a `byte[]`. There is no need to have `String data` at all in that first bit, just write the `byte[]` to the file.

Comment: @JasonC, This really should've been an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Egor I suppose, although unless the OP provides more information about the nature of the data, it's really more of an educated guess about his problem.

Comment: thank you @JasonC for explaining.
Actually I am creating (certificate).p12 files.
and the second solution works fine and I can read that certificate in android also.

Is there any way to find byteArray encoding ?

Comment: For what it's worth, the default encoding on Android is UTF-8.

Comment: @MohammadKhatri It's not trivial to determine the encoding of an arbitrary byte stream accurately, but you should have that information available *somehow*. Perhaps in one of the response headers (e.g. `Content-Type` for HTTP, or in multipart response info), or if your server is configured to always use the same encoding (and you have control over that) you can configure your client to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, constructing a `String` from bytes decodes the bytes according to the current default character encoding (if one is not explicitly specified). Also `String.getBytes()` does the same in reverse (and may not necessarily produce the same sequence of bytes that was used to create it).

A `String` holds text. If your data is raw binary data and is intended to be treated as such, you should not be storing it in a `String`, you should be storing it in a `byte[]`.

There is no need to have `String data` at all in that first bit, just write the `byte[]` to the file:

```
 byte[] responseBody = outstream.toByteArray();
 String data = new String(responseBody);
 ...
 out.write(data.getBytes());
```

Can just be:

```
 byte[] responseBody = outstream.toByteArray();
 ...
 out.write(responseBody);
```